# Unmountable SD card (error -110)

Tags: linux, sd-card

I'm trying to access data unto my micro sdcard (using a SD card adapter) from my Linux system.

But each time I try I get nothing but an error into dmesg:

> mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card

Also I don't seem to see the device listed under /dev (nothing called mmcXXX at least), and fdisk -l doesn't show it up neither.

On the other hand Windows is able to detect the micro sdcard with its 3 partitions (this is my e-reader micro sdcard) only asking me to format the sdcard because it can't read from it, which seems normal to me as there are partitions which should be ext3/ext4 but it prevent me from accessing the sd card content.

I found a lot of links about the Linux error but can't figure out a way to bring the micro sdcard back to life or if it's permanently damaged.

Any thoughts on it ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I faced recently a similar problem: Taking digital photos outdoor and didn't have a replacement battery. After the camera shut down on the empty battery, I several times took it out and back in. At the end the SD card got a corrupted file system (only), I hope.

Now the interesting part: The card is still readable on OpenSUSE 11.4 (ideapad S10e from 2009), getting -110 on OpenSUSE 11.3 (another old Lenovo) and the same on a new Fujitsu with OpenSUSE tumbleweed.

-110 error of mmc0 is likely a timeout (as found in some other forums)

The idea that the reader(s) are damaged, the pins of the card oxidized etc don't look like a way.

At the end I used photorec utility from:

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

on the system able to read the card. (On -110 you cannot see the device so no chance to work with it).

The utility can recover the files based on the file signature, understanding the content not the filesystem (provided the card is fresh formatted before use, so the content is not fragmented).

This is the third encounter with this effect. Once I succeeded by re-formatting on Windows, the reason was unknown and twice I pushed my luck with an empty battery. In both cases the above mentioned utility saved my photos completely. The cards were possible to format in the camera without any problem.

A wild guess is Linux kernel is confused in some versions when the card geometry info is corrupted. Timeouting after searching a sector not being on the card at all... Can anyone confirm?

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just bought a USB reader and it's working fine.

Might be the SD card adapter which was not working